# Large Volume exchanged, but not much price change in share

Tags: stocks, trading-volume, nse-india

In one of the stocks in India NSE, I often see that there is a large volume relatively to previous days exchanged, but the share price hasnt changed much.

[Natco Pharma NSE India 3-Dec-2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EDAV.png)

How can I do postmortem to understand this sudden surge in volume, but not price, is this some kind insider trading to manipulate share price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are probably block trades. See [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/blocktrade.asp), and for Indian markets specifically [here](https://www.indiainfoline.com/article/news-sector-others/what-are-block-deals-and-bulk-deals-113111500876_1.html) for more details on how block trades typically work.

Answer (score 0):

High volume days are generally caused by the release of news.  A recurring example of this is the day of an earnings announcement where volume surges but price may or may not change significantly.

Sometimes, volume surges across the board because the market is having an active day and many stocks see increased activity.

And as mentioned in the other answer, it could be due to block trades.